# C implementation of image processing dilation creating repeated patterns on the result image

Tags: c, image-processing, convolution

I'm trying to implement a dilation operation using C. Here's the code I've done

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "image.h"

#define IMG_ROWS 1280
#define IMG_COLS 1024
#define KERNEL_DIM 5 //kernel size

unsigned char imgIn[IMG_ROWS][IMG_COLS]; //grayscale values array
unsigned char imgOut[IMG_ROWS][IMG_COLS];

//Kernel initialization
int kernel[KERNEL_DIM][KERNEL_DIM] = {
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1}
};

int main()
{

    //fill the img matrix
    for(int idxRow = 0; idxRow < IMG_ROWS; idxRow++){
        for(int idxCol = 0; idxCol < IMG_COLS; idxCol++){
            imgIn[idxRow][idxCol] = img[idxRow*IMG_COLS + idxCol];
            imgOut[idxRow][idxCol] = 0;
        }
    }

    int max;
    int offset = KERNEL_DIM/2;
    //Iterates over the image ignoring the borders
    for(int idxRow = offset; idxRow < IMG_ROWS - offset; idxRow++){
        for(int idxCol = offset; idxCol < IMG_COLS - offset; idxCol++){
            max = 0;
            //Iterates over the kernel
            for(int krnRow = -offset; krnRow < offset + 1; krnRow++){
                for(int krnCol = -offset; krnCol < offset + 1; krnCol++){
                    //Max value under the kernel
                    if(kernel[offset + krnRow][offset + krnCol]*
                            imgIn[idxRow + krnRow][idxCol + krnCol] > max)        {
                        max = imgIn[idxRow + krnRow][idxCol + krnCol];
                    }
                }
            }

            imgOut[idxRow][idxCol] = max;
        }
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("ps_dil.log", "w");

    for(int idxRow = 0; idxRow < IMG_ROWS; idxRow++){
        for(int idxCol = 0; idxCol < IMG_COLS; idxCol++){
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", imgOut[idxRow][idxCol]);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;

}
```

As you can see, my input image is in the `imgIn` array and my structuring element is in the `kernel` array, where all the elements are set to 1. Also, I'm not processing the borders, keeping it's pixels with the value 0.

The input image comes from a 1D array, generated with the following matlab script:

```matlab
function saveAsCArray( I )
[nRows, nCols] = size(I);

cFile = fopen('image.h', 'w');
fprintf(cFile, 'unsigned char img[%d] = {', (nRows*nCols));

for row = 1:nRows
    for col = 1:nCols
        if row == nRows && col == nCols
            fprintf(cFile, '%d};', I(row, col));
        else
            fprintf(cFile, '%d,', I(row, col));
        end
    end
    fprintf(cFile, '\n');
end

fclose(cFile);
```

end

The output log file is convert back to an image with the following script:

```matlab
function intFileToImg( fileName, imgName, imgSizeRow, imgSizeCol)

    A = dlmread(fileName);
    A = uint8(A);
    A = reshape(A, imgSizeRow, imgSizeCol);
    A = rot90(A,3);
    I = mat2gray(A);
    I = flip(I, 2);
    imwrite(I, imgName);
    imshow(I);

end
```

I implemented the dilation in a way that the output pixel receives the value of the maximum pixel inside the kernel window. The problem is that my output image is showing some weird repetitions, which I really think that is related to some indexing mistake. Unfortunately I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my input:

[image]

Here is my output with 5x5 Kernel:
[image]

Here is my output with 3x3 Kernel:
[image]

Please, can someone take a look at the code and help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your kernel row and column probably don't start at `-offset` but at `0` in the line starting `for(int krnRow = -offset` and the next line.

Comment: (1) This is only a valid dilation if `kernel` contains only 0 and 1 values. For non-binary kernels, you need to add the image and kernel values. (2) Your result looks indeed like an indexing problem. Unfortunately we can't tell what's wrong because you didn't include a [mcve]. We need to see how `imgIn` and `imgOut` are defined to understand where your indexing goes wrong. Likely you're mixing up width and height of the image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did it so my indexing of the pixel neighbours would be more easy.

Comment: @CrisLuengo My kernel only contains  0 and 1 values, sorry for omitting this info. Also, edited the post adding the initialization of both input and output images. My input comes from an 1D array containing the grayscale values of the pixels and my output image is initialized with zeros.

Comment: I really think the initialization is ok. I guess the problem is in the if or the kernel loop. When I substitute the if for *max = imgIn[idxRow][idxCol]* the imgOut looks the same as the imgIn.

Comment: Try changing to `imgOut[..][..] = idxRow` and then try `imgOut[..][..] = idxCol`.

Comment: I've tried the suggestions, both gave me correct results. *idxRow* and *idxCol* looks ok, also the *imgIn[idxRow][idxCol + 1] returned the shifted image, as expected. I printed the *idxRow + offset* and *idxCol + offset* to verify it's values and I think they're ok too. Just edited my post with the full code. I still guess the error is inside the kernel loop. but can't find out where...

Comment: Did a test with a 256x256 image. Gave me a correct result. But I have no ideia why with the big image of 1280x1024 it didn't works.

Comment: Just some more information: when I tried to use a 3x3 kernel, the problem persists, but with three repetitions of the moon. Put the image in my main post.

Comment: The shift worked, depending on how much i add to the index, what i think is a normal behaviour. Also, the program worked on a 210 x 240 image. About my input and output, i'm doing this way to put the code in a hardware we use in university, where the systems for input and output are not yet finished. But first I need to test it on my PC. I did a scritp in matlab that reads a image and generates and unsigned char array from it and another script that reads this log file and generates the image. Will add their codes on the question.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's complete, and I can see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting the image to a linear array, you write each row consecutively (row-major). But then when converting the linear array back to an image, you use this sequence:

```matlab
A = reshape(A, imgSizeRow, imgSizeCol);
A = rot90(A,3);
I = mat2gray(A);
I = flip(I, 2);
```

MATLAB is column-major, which is why you needed the `rot90` in there. But because of that, you should also switch the row and column sizes:

```matlab
A = reshape(A, imgSizeCol, imgSizeRow).';
I = mat2gray(A);
```

Note also that `rot90` + `flip` is the same as transposing the matrix, which is what you actually need (going from a row-major matrix to a column-major one, you need to swap the two dimensions, which is what transposing does).

---

You should also fix these two lines of code in your C program:

```c
#define IMG_ROWS 1280
#define IMG_COLS 1024
```

The image you posted as the input has 502 rows and 622 columns.

I created this MATLAB script:

```matlab
% Load image
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u3bK.png');
I = I(:,:,1); % Keep only the first channel

% Write image
[nRows, nCols] = size(I);
cFile = fopen('image.h', 'w');
fprintf(cFile, '#define IMG_ROWS %d\n', nRows);
fprintf(cFile, '#define IMG_COLS %d\n', nCols);
fprintf(cFile, 'unsigned char img[%d] = {', (nRows*nCols));
fprintf(cFile, '%d,', I.'); % Note transpose!
fprintf(cFile, '};\n');
fclose(cFile);

% Compile & run C code
!gcc so.c -o so
!./so

% Load output
A = dlmread('ps_dil.log');
A = uint8(A);
A = reshape(A, nCols, nRows).';
imshow(A);
```

The file `so.c` is the C code you posted, but with the two lines defining `IMG_ROWS` and `IMG_COLS` removed. The `image.h` file I create here writes those two lines. This is the output, a perfectly fine dilation:

[image: output of code above]

Comment: Hi, tried to modify my matlab script but I'm still getting the wrong results. What I did was to remove the `rot90` and  the `flip` and replaced the `A = reshape(A, imgSizeRow, imgSizeCol);` by `A = reshape(A, imgSizeCol, imgSizeRow).';`. I also removed the `mat2gray` as I just realized it's creating a double matrix.